# Eclipse key binding to expand one level in tree views (OSX)

Tags: ios, eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts, expand

New Mac user here - is there a way to expand Eclipse tree views (Package Explorer, Search Results, etc.) **one level at a time** on OSX? I've done a lot of searching, and I'm starting to pull my hair out :)

In Windows/Linux, I've used `*` (numpad multiply) to expand one level at a time, but can't find the equivalent (or find a custom key binding that works) on OSX.

*Note: I know that `option+right/left` will expand/collapse all, but I'm specifically looking for one level of expansion at a time.*

Using:

- Eclipse Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
- MacOS: Sierra 10.12.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter (<kbd>⮐</kbd>) opens / closes a single level as does <kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>←</kbd>.

Comment: Well, that was ridiculously simple :|
Thanks!